# Why doesn't my code for responsive Google Forms iFrame work on all browsers & devices?

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, responsive-design, google-forms

I've made the iframe for our Google Form on a Wordpress website responsive and it does work on some devices using certain browsers, but not everywhere:

- Windows Firefox: works
- Windows Chrome: doesn't work
- iPhone Safari & Chrome: works
- Android Firefox & Chrome: doesn't work

Using the newest browser versions by the way.
Here's the code that I used:

```
<div class="resp-container-1">
<iframe class="resp-iframe-1" src="XXX" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">Wird geladen...</iframe>
</div>
```

and

```
.resp-container-1 {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 75%;
}

.resp-iframe-1 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0;
}
```

Please find screenshots below.

I've checked, double-checked and fiddled around with it, but I can't figure out how to tweak the code. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Victoria

[Windows Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVtUV.jpg)

[Windows Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaOmT.jpg)

[iPhone Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0IMj.jpg)

[Android Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc15U.png)

Comment: Why are you add `position: absolute` in iframe? Is that any specific reason? Just remove absolute position from the iframe..

Comment: @MinalChauhan because that’s how the general technique to make an iframe “responsive”, i.e. keep a certain aspect ratio at different screen/container widths, works …

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve] that reproduces the specific problem you are encountering - the minimal snippet you have shown above does not seem suitable to do that.